# Mule ESB execute script from Groovy with unicode params

Tags: unicode, groovy, mule

I have this little chain of components in my Mule ESB project:

```
<set-payload value="Получена заявка ##[sessionVars['ticketID']]" doc:name="Set SMS Text"/>
<scripting:transformer doc:name="Send SMS" ignoreBadInput="true">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
        def command = ["/tmp/call.sh", message.payload]

        def proc = command.execute()
        proc.waitFor()
    ]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

And /tmp/call.sh listing:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $@ > /tmp/call.out
```

When message passes Mule chain in /tmp/call.out I can see "Џолучена заЯвка #4041" instead of expected "Получена заявка #4041" ("Получена заявка" - Russian words), i.e. there is a problem with unicode chars output and there are no problems with ASCII chars.

When I check /tmp/groovy.out with HEX editor I see that all Russain chars has 1-byte lenght (in unicode that must be 2-bytes length), i.e. output of my Groovy component is not unicode.

There is no problem with unicode output to Mule log when I user Echo and Logger components. Also in SMTP component everything is perfect: I successfully receive letters in unicode from Mule.

Can you help me with unicode arguments in Mule ESB with Groovy command call?

Comment: what does running `locale` at the command line show your machine's locale is set to?

Comment: `$ locale
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: And you've got `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the top of your Mule script?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have the same project as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924084/mule-esb-groovy-unicode-output-issue

Comment: I'm stumped then...  Running (outside Mule) a groovy script `def s = "Получена заявка ##[sessionVars['ticketID']]" ; [ '/tmp/call.sh', s ].execute()` works for me...

Comment: Yes. Outside Mule this works for me too... I have problem with execute in Groovy only in Mule. Can't find any way to use UTF-8 for command execution params.

Comment: Solved by selecting UTF-8 ecoding in Run configuration options (menu Run -> Run configurations...). By default it was MacCyrilic encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by selecting UTF-8 ecoding in Run configuration options (menu Run -> Run configurations...). By default it was MacCyrilic encoding.